# How to fix 'A feed could not be found' error 200 when trying to add childcaredaily.org's RSS feed to another website?

Tags: wordpress, rss, blogs, feed, atom-feed

I am trying to display blog post from one website to another website. I searched for the /feed/ so I can add recent blogs from childcaredaily.org to another website but I keep getting this message "A feed could not be found at `https://childcaredaily.org/feed/`; the status code is `200` and content-type is `text/html; charset=UTF-8`What does this mean? How can I move forward.

I tried adding RSS in the widgets and I've tried changing the settings in read to make post page: "blog"

Answer (score 0):

There is not an RSS feed available at `https://childcaredaily.org/feed/`. Visiting that URL redirects to the site’s frontpage, which is why the status code is `200 OK` (everything is working) and the content type is HTML.